# Setup OkHttp Proxy at runtime when using Hilt

Tags: android, proxy, retrofit, okhttp, dagger-hilt

Hilt network module is setup like below:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkModule {
    private val TIMEOUT_UNIT = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    private val TIMEOUT_MILLIS: Long = 10000

    @Provides
    fun provideApi(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService =
        retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, converter: Converter.Factory): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(converter)
            .build()

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        builder.connectTimeout(3 * TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
        builder.readTimeout(6 * TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
        builder.writeTimeout(12 * TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
        builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        if (condition == true) {
            builder.proxy(Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("localhost", HTTP_PROXY_PORT)))
        }
        return builder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        if (BuildConfig::DEBUG.get()) {
            loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        } else {
            loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
        }
        return loggingInterceptor
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideConverterFactory(): Converter.Factory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create()
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesGson(): Gson {
        return Gson()
    }
}
```

I want to customize the retrofit instance at runtime with or without the proxy according to some condition. How do I do that?

Koin had unloadModule option for reinitializing modules, does Hilt has any similar feature or behaviour?